# Log file location not being picked from bootstrap.properties or external configuration service(spring-cloud-config)

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-boot

I have used spring-cloud-config to externalize my service configuration properties. One of the properties that I have externalized is the location of the log file (using log4j.xml) 
e.g.

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="File" value="${broker.log.location}/${broker.name.log}.log"/>
```

My understanding was that boostrap.properties file is used during the bootstrap phase and the properties defined there should be resolved. However I see that these properties do not get resolved. Same is the case when this is provided by the config service. The only way it resolves When I pass the location as jvm argument
e.g.

```
-Dbroker.name.log=broker1 -Dbroker.log.location=/tmp/rvm_logs/broker
```

This also means that these properties cannot be fetched from an external configuration service? Am I doing something incorrect. Why do these properties not get loaded from boostrap.properties or external configuration service. I am using spring-cloud Brixton.M4 releasetrain. I can paste specific code snippets if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has ever been able to do property resolution from Spring environment properties to log4j.xml. If you use logback there is the `logback-spring.xml` route (that file is filtered by Spring Boot and applied to logback, per the docs). There's nothing specific to Spring Cloud here either, so just look it all up in the Spring Boot user guide if you need to know more.

Comment: Thanks @DaveSyer. I will try with logback

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the problem I had was how to externalize the log file location when using spring-cloud-config. As Dave pointed out this will not work with log4j. However its quite simple with logback. For those having a similar requirement define a logback-spring.xml in your resource folder 
e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
  <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

Now the log file location can be provided via property `logging.file` in your external configuration file for your service. A sample service-configuration file can be found @ https://github.com/rixonmathew/rvm_config/blob/master/broker-service.properties

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, this example logback.xml is redundant (it's the default). Also the log4j logging system in Spring Boot *does* accept a log file location in `logging.file`, so if you stick with the handful of properties that Boot supports out of the box (all in the user guide I believe) you never need to do the above.